# Simple Question

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

hello guys help me please.
Is it correct to say "how do you think the weather is going to be next week?"
or we should add **like**- "how do you think the weather is going to be **like** next week?"
thank

Comment: I would change the *how* to *what*, then the second one sounds most natural to me.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not correct! That's to say, it's not idiomatic. If you wanted to ask that question, you would have to begin with **What**, not **how**.

Most people would probably ask one of the following:

> What's the weather forecast/outlook for next week?
>   What kind of weather will we have next week?
>   What kind of weather should we expect next week?

or, using **how**

> How do you think the weather will turn out next week?

If you want to use **like**,

> What do you think the weather will be like next week?

Comment: That's to say you want to say that it's a possible case but not habitual and idiomatic?